# Formatting .min($prices) as comma separated

Tags: php, formatting

I have a piece of code that finds the cheapest variant of the product and displays it as "price from". But I can't modify the code so that there is a space between thousands.

```
<?php function price_table($pid){
$productModel = VmModel::getModel('product');
$ids = $productModel->getProductChildIds($pid);
$prods = $productModel->getProducts($ids);
$customfieldsModel = VmModel::getModel ('Customfields');
$prods->customfields = $customfieldsModel->getCustomEmbeddedProductCustomFields ($product->allIds,0,-1, true);
$html='';
if (!empty($prods)){
$prices=Array();
foreach ($prods as $p){
$prices[]=$p->prices['salesPrice'];
}
if (count($prices>1)){
$html.='<p> <span class="redtext bold">Cena od '.min($prices).',- Kč</span></p>';
}

}

echo $html;
}

echo price_table($this->product->virtuemart_product_id); ?>
```

I need setup this line

```
$html.='<p> <span class="redtext bold">Cena od '.min($prices).',- Kč</span></p>';
```